# Laravel / Lumen - Reflection Exception Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, lumen

I am trying to inject a Manager class into toe Service Container of Lumen. My goal is to have a single instance of `LogManager` which is available in the whole application via `app(LogManager::class)`.

Everytime i try to access this shortcut i get the following exeption:

```
[2017-03-23 16:42:51] lumen.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class LogManager does not 
exist in /vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:681
```

**LogManager.php** (i placed that class in the same location where my models are (app/LogManager.php))

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\LogEntry;

class LogManager
{
...
}
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\LogManager;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(LogManager::class, function ($app) {
        return new LogManager();
    });
}
}
```

I uncommented the line `$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);` in `bootstrap/app.php`

I think that i missed something with the correct namespacing or placement of the classes espaccially **LogManager**. Maybe some one is willing to give me a hint?

If you need some more informations just give me a hint!

Comment: I often had the same problem. Every time it was some syntax error in the config/*.php or .env files.

Comment: The problem probably occurs when trying to get a concrete type for a given abstract in the Container. Where and how are you resolving the LogManager from the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class and your service provider look fine. However, wherever you're calling `app(LogManager::class)` also needs to know the fully qualified name of the class.

Either make sure you have `use App\LogManager` at the top of the file, or change your call to `app(\App\LogManager::class)`.

Comment: In addition to setting a complete namespace he could also register it as `LogManager`: `$this->app->singleton('LogManager', function ($app) {
    return new \App\LogManager;
});`

Comment: @MelvinKoopmans While technically that would solve the current issue, that would break any existing code that resolves the class out of the container using the correct fully qualified name. Additionally, that would remove the ability to auto inject this dependency though type hints.